# Return statement in promise's then

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm learning Promises (vanilla es6 promises from [this shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/)) and I have 2 functions, each of them is returning a new Promise and a 3rd function called `magic()`, that calls the 2 functions and also returns a Promise.

Sample code:

```
var CreatorX = {
    "create": function() {
        var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.console.log("created");
                resolve(22);
            }, 100);
        });
        return p;
    }
};

var CreatorY = {
    "create": function(id) {
        window.console.log("id " + id);
        var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                resolve(2244);
            }, 5);
        });
        return p;
    }
};
```

And here's the magic:

```
function magic() {
       return CreatorX.create().then(function(d) {
            CreatorY.create(d); // shouldn't it be 'return CreatorY...'?
        });
}

var r = magic();
r.then(function() {
    console.log("Done");
}, function(err){console.error("oops")});
```

My question is, why does this work? I don't have return statement at the line with `CreatorY.create(d)` in the magic function and yet it seems to work. Should the `return` be there? Is it just a coincidence that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return something from the Promise function, the promise is resolved with the value you return. The returned value from the promised function will be passed on to the chained promise function.

In your case, you are not returning anything explicitly. So, JavaScript will resolve the promise with `undefined` and that will be available to the

```
function() {
    console.log("Done");
}
```

function. But you are ignoring the resolved value from the previous promise. If you actually want to make use of it, then change the function to

```
function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Now you will be able to see the actual resolved value.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that the console.log in  CreateY.create() methods is not part of the promise as such, it is being called synchronously, once I move the logging to the timeout's functions, it is clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `magic()` returns a promise so the `CreatorY.create(d)` call runs, but when you say `r.then(...` that is running the promise from the call to `return CreatorX.create().then(...`